# Sympy strange interpretation of a summation

Tags: sympy

Let us consider following code

```
from sympy import *
n = Symbol('n', real=True)
k = Symbol('k', real=True)

f = lambda n: summation(exp(sqrt(k)), (k, 1, n))

display(f(n))
display(f(5))
```

It results in ( [see latex screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByAQZ.png) )

```
Piecewise((n*exp(c3_), Eq(exp(c2_), 1)), ((exp(c2_) - exp(c2_)**(n + 1))*exp(c3_)/(-exp(c2_) + 1), True))
E + exp(sqrt(2)) + exp(sqrt(3)) + exp(2) + exp(sqrt(5))
```

**Questions**

- What are the constans `c1_`, `c2_` and `c3_`?
- Why did not the first `display` return a summation formula?
- How did the sympy produce the second output, assumig `f` is represented as in the first output?